# Trouble reshaping array for TensorFlow ML

Tags: arrays, shapes, reshape, tensor

Trying to reshape dataframe for input into TensorFlow model.

After retrieving data from excel file, putting into dataframe, segregating between features (X) & labels (y), splitting between train and test (80/20), I try to do a quick visualization and get an error.

Here is first part of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn

df = pd.read_excel('syn_data_hotel.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1', header = 0)

#split X (features) & y (labels)
X = df.drop('Total_Weighted', axis=1)
y = df['Total_Weighted']

print(X.ndim, X.shape, y.ndim, y.shape)    #to make sure we dropped our label

#split our data between train/test 80/20
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)    #set random state for reproducible splits

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c='b', label='Training data')
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, c='g', label='Testing data')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

```
2 (5000, 11) 1 (5000,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Will\Desktop\Dropbox\School C\Python\TF_NN.py", line 22, in <module>
    plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c='b', label='Training data')
  File "C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2862, in scatter
    __ret = gca().scatter(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1459, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4584, in scatter
    raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

What is best way to get shape of X & y the same without losing integrity of data?

Tried slicing to to -1, but no avail.